# Multiple consumers, is it possible to clone a queue (gevent)?

Tags: python, queue, gevent

I'd like to do something like that (1 queue, and multiple consumers):

```
import gevent
from gevent import queue

q=queue.Queue()
q.put(1)
q.put(2)
q.put(3)
q.put(StopIteration)

def consumer(qq):
    for i in qq:
        print i

jobs=[gevent.spawn(consumer,i) for i in [q,q]]

gevent.joinall(jobs)
```

But it's not possible ... the queue is consumed by job1 ... so job2 would block forever.
It gives me the exception `gevent.hub.LoopExit: This operation would block forever`.

I would that each consumer will be able to consume the full queue from start. (should display 1,2,3,1,2,3 or 1,1,2,2,3,3 ... nevermind)

One idea should be to clone the queue before spawning, but it's not possible using copy (shallow/deep) module ;-(

Is there another way to do that ?

[EDIT]
what do you think of that ?

```
import gevent
from gevent import queue

class MasterQueueClonable(queue.Queue):
    def __init__(self,*a,**k):
        queue.Queue.__init__(self,*a,**k)

        self.__cloned = []
        self.__old=[]

    #override
    def get(self,*a,**k):
        e=queue.Queue.get(self,*a,**k)
        for i in self.__cloned:  i.put(e) # serve to current clones
        self.__old.append(e)              # save old element
        return e

    def clone(self):
        q=queue.Queue()
        for i in self.__old: q.put(i)   # feed a queue with elements which are out
        self.__cloned.append(q)         # stock the queue, to be able to put newer elements too
        return q

q=MasterQueueClonable()
q.put(1)
q.put(2)
q.put(3)
q.put(StopIteration)

def consumer(qq):
    for i in qq:
        print id(qq),i

jobs=[gevent.spawn(consumer,i) for i in [q.clone(), q ,q.clone(),q.clone()]]
gevent.joinall(jobs)
```

It's based on the idea of RyanYe. There is a "master queue" without a dispatcher.
My master queue override the GET method, and can dispatch to an ondemand clone.
And more, a "clone" can be created after the start of the masterqueue (with the __old trick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to create a greenlet to dispatch the work to consumers. Example code:

```
import gevent
from gevent import queue

master_queue=queue.Queue()
master_queue.put(1)
master_queue.put(2)
master_queue.put(3)
master_queue.put(StopIteration)

total_consumers = 10
consumer_queues = [queue.Queue() for i in xrange(total_consumers)]

def dispatcher(master_queue, consumer_queues):
    for i in master_queue:
        [j.put(i) for j in consumer_queues]
    [j.put(StopIteration) for j in consumer_queues]

def consumer(qq):
    for i in qq:
        print i

jobs=[gevent.spawn(dispatcher, q, consumer_queues)] + [gevent.spawn(consumer, i) for i in consumer_queues]
gevent.joinall(jobs)
```

UPDATE: Fix missing StopIteration for consumer queues. Thanks arilou for pointing it out.

Comment: Sure ... the troubble is that if there are "50Mb" which transit in the master_queue .... there will be "500Mb" (50*10) in consumer_queues.

I'd like to create consumer queues on demand, if needed.

Comment: Two points I want to mention 1) We're talking about 10x references instead of 10x actual data bytes. It's a huge difference if each item is a complex object. 2) We're talking about '10x memory access' instead of '10x memory space'. In most cases, that won't be the bottleneck. Actually, since each consumer queue needs to access all the items in master queue. Thus, '10x memory access' is inevitable.

Comment: You're right ... but in my case, the master queue will contain chunck of mp3 stream. I need "clones", because a lot of "mp3 http clients" request many times the stream (to get informations, size, tags, format ...) ...

Comment: In that case, I would suggest that instead of cloning queues, you should only keep one copy of the mp3 stream data in memory, and each client only holds a pointer of their current position in the stream. That will be more efficient since it avoids cloning data. It's off the topic, but hope it helps solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've [added](https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/changeset/1f85ba7204d8) `copy()` method to Queue class:

```
>>> import gevent.queue
>>> q = gevent.queue.Queue()
>>> q.put(5)
>>> q.copy().get()
5
>>> q
<Queue at 0x1062760d0 queue=deque([5])>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, and I believe that it missed this feature. It's a great add! But in my case (I can't test now ;-( ), what happens if you add another element in 'q' after the ".copy" ... is this element added to the copied version too ?

Answer (score 0):

In the answer by Ryan Ye one line is missed in the end of the dispatcher() function:
[j.put(StopIteration) for j in consumer_queues]
Without it we still get 'gevent.hub.LoopExit: This operation would block forever' since 'for i in master_queue' loop doesn't copy StopIteration exception into the consumer_queues.

(Sorry, I can't leave comments yet so I write it as a separete answer.)